# Query on order of certificates in PEM file used by springboot 2.7

Tags: spring-boot

1. We are using `Springboot 2.7.1` version with `Openjdk11` in `RHEL 8.2`
   We are using `PEM` files for `private and public keys` and passing them to `springboot` application using `properties` `server.ssl.certificate and server.ssl.certificate-private-key`.
2. Private key is a `PEM` file having tags:

   ```
   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
         and 
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```
3. `PEM` file mentioned in `server.ssl.certificate` has the `public certificate`, `intermediate and root certificate`:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
        and 
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```

If `PEM` file in `server.ssl.certificate` has certificates in order of public, intermediate and root then we are getting error:

```
"org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
 Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 Error adding certificates to KeyStore: 
 Key protection algorithm not found: 
 java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid"
```

But if `PEM` file in `server.ssl.certificate` has only `public certificate or certificates` in order public, root and intermediate then springboot application is starting up without error.

Is this expected behavior or some spring exception or bug?
If it is expected behavior, please share us some documentation or details on `what is the order of certificates to be maintained when using PEM file with springboot?`.

Full error message is:

```
2023-05-03 10:48:06.409  WARN 17264 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
        Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
        org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
        Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error adding certificates to KeyStore: 
        Key protection algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: 
        Certificate chain is not valid
2023-05-03 10:48:06.527 ERROR 17264 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    Error adding certificates to KeyStore: Key protection algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid

    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.scb.fsp.cloud.mft.support.MftSupportApplication.main(MftSupportApplication.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Error adding certificates to KeyStore: 
    Key protection algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.getKeyManagers(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.customize(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowWebServerFactoryDelegate.createBuilder(UndertowWebServerFactoryDelegate.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
     Error adding certificates to KeyStore:
     Key protection algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.createKeyStore(CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.getKeyStore(CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.getKeyStore(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.getKeyManagers(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:111)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.setKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:688)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:585)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:111)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.addCertificates(CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.createKeyStore(CertificateFileSslStoreProvider.java:78)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.setKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:635)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```